# How to test commit_manually inside Django unittests

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-unittest

How do you test Django code that uses [commit_manually()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) from a unittest?

I have a long-running method that deletes large numbers of records, enough so that it can't keep all those changes in a single transaction without consuming all system memory. So I wrap it in `@commit_manually` and periodically call `commit()`.

However, in Django 1.6, all unittests are now wrapped in `transaction.atomic()`, so if I try and make any manual commits, I get the error:

django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.

What's a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using TransactionTestCase instead of TestCase should give you this ability.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/advanced/#advanced-features-of-transactiontestcase

Comment: @Cerin did using TransactionTestCase fix your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All that gives me is "TransactionManagementError: Your database backend doesn't behave properly when autocommit is off. Turn it on before using 'atomic'." I'm using Sqlite3 as my unittest db backend.